# Http 404 after requesting to endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write Spring application in Spring 3.0.x (yes I want that version). Made a really simple method that returns String.

```
package fitnessapp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Hello {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sayHello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

After calling http://localhost:8080/sayHello I'm getting 404 don't know why.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 682
Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 18:44:04 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Connection: keep-alive

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title>
    <style type="text/css">body {
        font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

   ...
</head>
<body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1>
<hr class="line"/>
<p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
<p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing
    to disclose that one exists.</p>
<hr class="line"/>
<h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.60</h3></body>
</html>
```

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.60.

My pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>stara</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

DispartcherServlet-context.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="fitnessapp"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

In logs I get

```
04-Dec-2020 21:22:38.073 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2f66c1fd: defining beans [hello,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
04-Dec-2020 21:22:38.310 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/sayHello] onto handler 'hello'
04-Dec-2020 21:22:38.310 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/sayHello.*] onto handler 'hello'
04-Dec-2020 21:22:38.311 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/sayHello/] onto handler 'hello'
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong to make this Controller work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

should become:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sayHello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and rename your DispartcherServlet-context.xml properly to myServlet-servlet.xml.

Your dependency in the pom should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

or something like that.

Comment: So I resolved first problem. I had to move webapp package under src/main, but still getting 404. I edited question with updated files.

Comment: Chaning utl-pattern does not change anythhing  + I can have servlet named with DispatcherServlet.

Comment: Open your war file with 7zip, and check if you have the html page at the right location as everything else (web.xml) and so on. I think by default Spring looks for the context in a file named {servlet-name}-servlet.xml.

Comment: I dont have any .html files. Why should I have any?

Comment: A web app should have a default landing page. Anyway if you create the page and map it in your context file you could get more information on the problem. As a general suggestion read Spring documentation and examples more carefully.